# Gauss-Newton normal equations with norm of residual

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares, computer-vision

The Wiki definition of [Gauss-Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) has the following scalar cost function:

${\displaystyle S({\boldsymbol {\beta }})=\sum _{i=1}^{m}r_{i}^{2}({\boldsymbol {\beta }}).}$

where $r_i(\beta)$ are scalar functions of parameters $\beta$.

In this document, the residuals $r_i$ are defined as

${\displaystyle r_{i}({\boldsymbol {\beta }})=y_{i}-f\left(x_{i},{\boldsymbol {\beta }}\right).}$

This assumes that $y_i$ and $f(x_i, \beta)$ are both scalar.

But in some application domains, say [Bundle Adjustment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_adjustment#Mathematical_definition), $y_i, f(x_i, \beta) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ as they represent 2D points in a sensor.

Therefore, $r_i(\beta) = ||y_i - f(x_i, \beta)||$.

Can we still use the same GNA normal equations to solve such a problem when $r_i$ is wrapped in some kind of a distance metric like the Euclidean norm?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I wrote some notes about the sparse Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm for bundle adjustment (with Python code) [here](https://github.com/danielvoconnor/MultipleViewGeometry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the functions $f_i : \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^p$ for $i = 1, \ldots, m$ are differentiable and the function $S:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R$ is defined by
$$
\tag{1} S(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^m \| f_i(\beta) - y_i \|^2.
$$
Our goal is to minimize $S$.

The way the Gauss-Newton method works is that at each iteration we linearize the functions $f_i$ and then solve the resulting least squares problem. Let $\beta^t$ be our estimate of $\beta$ at iteration $t$ of the Gauss-Newton method. (The $t$ is a superscript, not an exponent.) Then at iteration $t+1$ of the Gauss-Newton method we solve the least squares problem
$$
\text{minimize} \quad \sum_{i=1}^m \| f_i(\beta^t) + \underbrace{f_i'(\beta^t)}_{p \times k} (\beta - \beta^t) - y_i \|^2.
$$
The optimization variable is $\beta \in \mathbb R^k$. To solve this least squares problem, we can set the gradient equal to $0$, which yields
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m 2 \underbrace{f_i'(\beta^t)^T}_{k \times p} \big(f_i(\beta^t) + \underbrace{f_i'(\beta^t)}_{p \times k} (\beta - \beta^t) - y_i \big) = 0.
$$
The solution to this linear system is $\beta^{t+1}$.

---

A slightly different (but equivalent) way to look at this is to define
$$
f(\beta) = \begin{bmatrix} f_1(\beta) \\ f_2(\beta) \\ \vdots \\ f_m(\beta) \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_m \end{bmatrix}
$$
and note that equation (1) can be written equivalently as
$$
S(\beta) = \| f(\beta) - y \|^2.
$$
We can use the Gauss-Newton method to minimize $\| f(\beta) - y \|^2$. At each iteration of the Gauss-Newton method, we linearize $f$ and then solve the resulting least squares problem. Let $\beta^t$ be our estimate of $\beta$ at iteration $t$ of the Gauss-Newton method. The least squares problem that we solve at iteration $t+1$ is
$$
\text{minimize} \quad \| f(\beta^t) + f'(\beta^t)(\beta - 
\beta^t) - y \|^2.
$$
The optimization variable is $\beta \in \mathbb R^k$.
We can solve this least squares problem by setting the gradient equal to $0$, which yields
$$
f'(\beta^t)^T \bigg( f(\beta^t) + f'(\beta^t)(\underbrace{\beta - \beta^t}_{\Delta \beta}) - y \bigg) = 0
$$
or equivalently
$$
\tag{2} f'(\beta^t)^T f'(\beta^t) \Delta \beta = f'(\beta^t)^T(y - f(\beta^t)).
$$
Our new estimate of $\beta$ is
$$
\beta^{t+1} = \beta^t + \Delta \beta
$$
where $\Delta \beta$ is computed by solving the "normal equations" (2).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Do you think this can somehow be reduced to the Wikipedia derivation or is that completely different?

Comment: @Carpetfizz The viewpoint given in the Notes section of the Wikipedia article is the way I like to think about the Gauss-Newton method. I believe what I’ve posted here is similar to what’s stated in the Notes section.

Comment: thanks but I'm still a little confused. The solution in the Wikipedia article only has a single Jacobian but here you have a sum of $m$ Jacobians? Do you mind adding one more line to your answer which turns the last summation into the normal equations?

Comment: @Carpetfizz I added some further explanation; does that clarify the issue?

Comment: it does, thank you so much!

Comment: One more question - in the second derivation, $f(\beta)$ is a matrix valued function $f : \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}$. What would the Jacobian $f'(\beta)$ look like here?

Perhaps we just "flatten" $f(\beta)$ into a $\mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{mp}$ function?

Comment: @Carpetfizz Note that $f_1(\beta)$ is a column vector, as is $f_2(\beta)$, etc. The output of $f$ is the vertical concatenation of all these column vectors $f_1(\beta), \ldots, f_m(\beta)$. So $f(\beta)$ is a column vector with shape $mp \times 1$. So yes, $f: \mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^{mp}$.

Answer (score 2):

The Gauss-Newton method can of course be used for $r_i$ defined by $||y_i-f(x_i,\beta)||$, where $y_i,f\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The way I think about the Gauss-Newton method is that we minimize $\sum_{i=1}^m  \|r_i(\beta)\|^2$ by linearizing the functions $r_i$ and solving the resulting least squares problem at each iteration. In this viewpoint we take $r_i(\beta) = f(x_i,\beta) - y_i$. I believe this is the standard way of doing it. If we took $r_i(\beta) = \| y_i - f(x_i, \beta)\|$, then linearizing $r_i$ would be more difficult / less clean, and in fact $r_i$ would not be a differentiable function.

Comment: The G.-N. method is just the Newton's method used for functions of the form $f(\beta)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m r_i^2(\beta)$, in which the Hessian is calculated only approximately with the help of the formula $(\nabla^2f)(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^m\nabla r_i \nabla r_i$ (which contains only first derivatives). Otherwise it is the standard Newton's method for minimization.

Comment: The full formula would be $(\nabla^2f)(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^m[\nabla r_i(\beta) \nabla r_i(\beta)+\nabla ^2 r_i (\beta) r_i(\beta)]$.